# Año Bisiesto con DateDiff SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Deseo conseguir en un procedimiento almaceando que al ingresar el año me arroje si tiene los 365 del año o los 366 si es año bisiesto

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE PruebasDeAñoBisiestos
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Año int

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '@Año/01/01', '@Año/12/31') AS Diferencia;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @Year INT
SELECT  @Year = 2012

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Year)+'0101', CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Year+1)+'0101')
```

Recuerda que el el `datediff` no es inclusivo de los límites, es decir si haces: `DATEDIFF(DAY, '20180521', '20180522')` te retornará `1` cuando para lo que buscas el resultado debiera ser `2`. Por eso el cáculo debe hacerse desde el primero de enero de un año al mismo día del otro.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar una diferencia de días entre los meses:

```sql
DECLARE @DiasFebrero TINYINT

SELECT @DiasFebrero = DATEDIFF(day,convert(varchar(8),@datInicial,120)+'01',
                               DATEADD(MONTH,1,convert(varchar(8),@datInicial,120)+'01'))
```